# How to fix Input arguments to function include colon operator error

Tags: matlab, statistics, montecarlo

```matlab
clc; clear

w = load('dimensionless_concentration_data.txt');
time = w(:,1);
C_mea = w(:,2);

figure(1)
 plot(time,C_mea,'*','LineWidth',1.5,'Color','r')
 xlabel('Time (seconds)','FontName','Arial','FontSize',16);ylabel('Dimensionless Concentration','FontName','Arial','FontSize',16) 
 set(gca,'LineWidth',1.5,'FontSize',16,'FontName','Arial')
  
grid on
hold on 

c0 = 0.2; %(mol m^-3) initial concentration
cin = 2; %(mol m^-2) mass flux
x = 0.02; %mass flux

t = 0:200:3600; %time vector
    
D = 10^-7 %m^2s^-1 diffusivity coefficient upper bound
C =@(x,t) c0 +(cin./(sqrt(4*pi*D*t)).*exp(-x.^2./(4*D*t)));


for i =1:1000
    D = rand(1) * 10^-7; 
    D_vals(i) = D;
    D_est = mean(D_vals);
    STD_dev = std(C_mea);
    C_dim(i,:) = C(i,:)./max(C(i,:)); %dimensionless concentration
    R_fit(i) = 1/(STD_dev.^2).*(C_dim(i,2)./C_mea(1)-1).^2 + (C_dim(i,end)./C_mea(end)-1).^2;
    drawnow 
    fprintf('%d         %d      %d',i,R_fit(i),D_est)
end
```

This code ends with this error:

```
Input arguments to function include colon operator. To input the colon character, use ':' instead.

Error in olasilikodev (line 31)
    C_dim(i,:) = C(i,:)./max(C(i,:)); %dimensionless concentration
```

I tried to solve this with this code:

```
C_dim = zeros(1000, length(t));
R_fit = zeros(1000, 1);
D_vals = zeros(1000, 1);
```

but it didn't work

My data:

```
% seconds    Diemnsonless concentration (C(1:length(t))/max(C))
300            0.02
500            0.16
1000           0.46
1250           0.65
1500           0.75
2200           0.88
2900           0.95
3200           0.97
3600           0.99
```

Comment: Because `C =@(x,t) …`, `C` is a function, not a matrix, and you can’t index into a function.

Comment: how can i turn it into matrix?

Comment: You probably just want to remove the `@(x,t)` part, so the rest is computed immediately and assigned to `C` as an array. The `@()` syntax creates an anonymous function (what’s called lambda in some other programming languages).

Comment: what's in dimensionless_concentration_data.txt ? any chance to assess the posted code with dimensionless_concentration_data.txt or part of it ?

Answer (score 0):

`C = @(x,t) c0 +(cin./(sqrt(4*pi*D*t)).*exp(-x.^2./(4*D*t)));` defines a function, so when you call `C(i,:)`, matlab tries to apply your formulat to `x=i` and `t=:`. This results in an error, because `:` is not a value.

I think you should just go ahead with the application of your formula to the variables, replacing the line with : `C = c0 +(cin./(sqrt(4*pi*D*t)).*exp(-x.^2./(4*D*t)));`

It results in a vector `C`, and you'll be able to compute `C(i)./max(C)`.